# ASUS PRIME B250 PRO + NVIDIA GTX 590 graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, asus

I have a problem with combing the two HW components given in the title. The board has two PCIEX16, one of them with x16 peed, the other one with x1 or x4 speed. When I plug  in the card into the x1-x4 slot it is possible to get it working. However, when I insert the card into the x16 slot the machine simply hangs. I cannot enter even the BIOS setup. Has anybody experienced this problem? Any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a hardware problem either on the GPU or the motherboard PCIe x16 port. The first thing you can try is to clean the PCIe contacts both in the GPU and motherboard using isopropyl alcohol together with a microfiber cloth or an old (but very clean) toothbrush while brushing or scrubbing lighly in the orientation of the contacts, up to down. Wet the cloth or brush with the alcohol and then scrub/brush the contacts on the GPU. For the motherboard contacts, I'd recommend using the brush dry and very lightly, since the contacts can get warped for being very sensitive. Remember to dry well after using the alcohol, let it dry for a few 5 minutes and later a dry cloth to remove any remaining, a light polish. Good luck.

Comment: Cleaning the motherboard pins with an object may damage to the pins, which could cause potentially serious damage to both components when the devices are powered.  Nothing more than clean, dry air should be used to remove any potential dust or debris from the motherboard's x16 socket.